# Post method data in Page_load

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a web service in C# and i need to send the data in post method and not in the url.

until now i get the data from a url :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

from the sender,and no i want to get the data in post.

Comment: Sounds like you need an introductory tutorial in ASP.NET web services. Google it, you'll find plenty of them out there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to access the data in POST, just do:

```
Request.Params["data_key"]
```

I'd advise you to put a break point on Page_Load and examine the contents of the Request.Params object and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Can we pass in a JSON object ?